# Thunks in sequence on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, redux-thunk

I have an app that fetches some user info on render. So when the app first boots up it fetches the data with the use of getUserInformation() function. User doesn't need to manually log in, the app is inside the company's internal network.

```html
export function getUserInformation() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    getUser()
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch(
          {type: GET_USER_SUCCESS, response: data}
        )
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(
          {type: GET_USER_FAILURE, response: error}
        )
      })
  }
}
```

Now I want to fetch the version of the app to be available in the whole app. But the API call can only be fired once the user is logged in (so getUser() was called successfully). Should I just add the

```
.then(getVersion())
```

in the getUserInformation() action?
It doesn't seem clean but I have no idea how can I approach it differently.

Comment: Well if `getVersion` should only run after `getUserInformation` then i don't see a better option.

Comment: [offtop] not `.then(getVersion())` but `.then(getVersion)` or your will get wrong ordering and may face race conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action creator is a proper place to dispatch actions in sequence. The documentation [covers this](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#should-i-dispatch-multiple-actions-in-a-row-from-one-action-creator):

> Using an async middleware like Redux Thunk certainly enables scenarios such as dispatching multiple distinct but related actions in a row, dispatching actions to represent progression of an AJAX request, dispatching actions conditionally based on state, or even dispatching an action and checking the updated state immediately afterwards.

In case user information and version actions need to be tested separately (they should be located in different modules) or be used separately, action creators can be combined. This requires to return promises to chain them. This also shows the limitation of `redux-thunk`:

```
function getUserInformation() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(
          {type: GET_USER_SUCCESS, response: await getUser()}
        )
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(
          {type: GET_USER_FAILURE, response: error}
        )
    }
  };
}

...

function getVersion() {
  return async (dispatch) => {...};
}

...

function getInitialData() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    await getUserInformation()(dispatch);
    // we need to use getState to check if there was an error
    // because getUserInformation returns a fulfilled promise any way
    await getVersion()(dispatch);
  };
}
```

It would make sense be to re-throw an error from `getUserInformation`, but it would be bad in case it's used separately from `getInitialData` because this would result in unhandled rejection. The alternative is even worse, to check if there was an error with `getState()`.

This scenario requires a more sophisticated middleware than `redux-thunk` which is [dead simple](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js) - possibly a custom middleware that is based on it and is capable of handling rejections.